# Session for multiple files when logged in?

Tags: php

I have **/admin/** folder with multiple files in it that get POST/GET and do certain things with my data base. The question is do I need to do (`if $_SESSION['isAdmin'] == true`) at the beginning of every file to enable access to those files only to **admin** who is logged in or there is some another more optimal way? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There needs to be some kind of authorization check to make a distinction between normal users and administrators.

How you do that depends on your application architecture: If you’re having multiple entry points (i.e. every file is independent), you will need to do the authorization check in every single entry point. Otherwise, if there is only one entry point (i.e. one single file handles all requests via parameters), you will just need one authorization check.

And one solution would be to store that information in the global session and check it every time a user needs to be an administrator to access an administrators’ resource.

Answer (score 0):

i believe it's the most optimal way

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Otherwise, some people may directly post to the pages without the checking. (Offcourse, if they have some gain by posting)